# How to get from a Method to the Annotations of its Parameters during Annotation-processing?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, method-parameters

During annotation processing I am currently processing the annotation of a method:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> elements, RoundEnvironment env) {
  Messager msg = processingEnv.getMessager();
  for (TypeElement te : elements) {
    for (Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te)) {
      processAnnotation(e, msg);
    }
  }
  return true;
}

private void processAnnotation(Element method, Messager msg) {
  final Info ann = method.getAnnotation(Info.class);
  assert method.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD;
  ....
```

I can get to the *types* (or its mirrors) of the parameters with

```
  final ExecutableType emeth = (ExecutableType)method.asType();
  final List<? extends TypeMirror> parameterTypes = emeth.getParameterTypes();
```

but how to I get to its annotations? I would like to check, if the method under consideration has any parameter with the annotation `@Input`. For example the processed source could be:

```
@Info
void myMethodOk(@Input String input) {  }

@Info
void myMethodNotOk(@Input String input) { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cast your method `Element` to `ExecutableElement`, then you can invoke `executableElement.getParamerers()`. This returns a list of `VariableElement`s, which you can get annotations from.